# Interpolate latitude, longitude, data in Python (structured grid inside a circle)

Tags: python, scipy, gis, interpolation, estimation

I have a set of latitude, longitude points with a data-variable e.g. drive-time from an address. These points have been created by sampling a **structured** grid and then **cutting out a circle**.

As such I don't think I can have a matrix of data because some columns will have more zeros/missing than others (the top and bottom parts of the circle) which may confuse the algorithm?

Ideally, I would like to fill in the circle with more points; e.g. at 5 decimal places such that instead of having 51.5454 and 51.5455 I have 51.54540, 51.54541, .... , 51.54550.

My data looks like this:

[image]

And I would like to fill in the gaps:

[image]

I have tried using:

```
from scipy.interpolate import RectSphereBivariateSpline
```

In the following fashion - (test-case), however I am not sure if this is the correct approach in general?

```
def geointerp(lats, lons, data, grid_size_deg, mesh=False):
    deg2rad = np.pi/180.
    new_lats = np.linspace(50, 51, 180/grid_size_deg)
    new_lons = np.linspace(-1, 1, 360/grid_size_deg)
    new_lats, new_lons = np.meshgrid(new_lats*deg2rad, new_lons*deg2rad)
    #We need to set up the interpolator object

    lut = RectSphereBivariateSpline(lons*deg2rad, lats*deg2rad, data)

    new_lats = new_lats.ravel()
    new_lons = new_lons.ravel()
    data_interp = lut.ev(new_lats,new_lons)

    if mesh == True:
        data_interp = data_interp.reshape((360/grid_size_deg, 180/grid_size_deg)).T

    return new_lats/deg2rad, new_lons/deg2rad, data_interp

# Read in-data
lats_in = []
lons_in = []
data_in = []
with open('interpolation_test.csv') as f:
    for x in csv.reader(f):
        lats_in.append(float(x[0]))
        lons_in.append(float(x[1]))
        data_in.append(float(x[2]))

# Interpolate:
lats_in = np.asarray(lats_in)
lons_in = np.asarray(lons_in)
data_in = np.asarray(data_in)
output_list = geointerp(lats_in, lons_in, data_in, 0.01)

#  Output
f = open('interpolation_test_out.csv', 'w', newline='')
w = csv.writer(f)
for out in output_list:
    w.writerow([out])
f.close()
```

Not to mention errors such as:

```
"if not v.size == r.shape[1]:
IndexError: tuple index out of range"
```

Comment: "interpolate the data to 3 d.p." ... What is "3 d.p."?

Comment: I'm pretty sure he means 3 decimal points, but I'm still confused about the overall question.

Comment: actoually i think '3 dp' means 3 dimensional data since his each point as three dimensions i.e. time, lan, lat.

Comment: Apologies for the confusion; I did mean 3 decimal places -> I want to create a fine(r) grid over my existing data

Comment: maybe try using the following - http://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/linear_model/plot_polynomial_interpolation.html

Comment: Apologies, I was missing the crucial part from my question -> the data is on a structured grid but in a circle (on a map). Given that; Nimrodshn I think scikit-learn might be a bit overkill? Sorry again for miss-representing the question